# SQL Get rows that doesn't appear in another table

Tags: sql

I have this SQL problem: I have tables A and B. Table A has columns `id` and `name`, Table B `amount` and `id` which is a foreign key to table `A.id`.

I need to return all table A rows that don't have their id stored in table B. Any ideas?

So the complete opposite is:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id;
```

Here row what I need is left out of result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `where` clause:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     b
     ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

You can also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id);
```

In most databases, the two methods typically have similar performance.

Comment: Officially this is called an "anti-join".